# Find duplicate row in a datatable by id - add the duplicate column values as concatented string to a new column then remove dulplicate column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have the following DataTable

```
RequestId  userID   ProductCode  ProductValue
1          "10004"  70           85.50        
2          "10004"  67           944.00
3          "10333"  30           97.00
4          "23344"  70           89.00
```

What I would like to achieve is the following - concatenating the `ProductCode` and `ProductValue` into a comma delimited string into a new column and any duplicate rows would be added to this comma delimited string. Then remove the duplicate row (order by the request id)

```
RequestId  userID   ProductCode  ProductValue NewColumn
1          "10004"  70           85.50        "70,85.50,67,944.00"
3          "10333"  30           97.00        "30,97.00"
4          "23344"  70           89.00        "70,89.00"
```

Is this possible using Linq - or would I have to loop through  the table and interrogate the fields as I go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var newTable = oldTable.Clone();
newTable.Columns.Add("NewColumn");
newTable = oldTable.AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("userID"))
                   .Select(g => {
                      var newRow = newTable.NewRow();
                      var firstRow = g.First();
                      for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) newRow[i] = firstRow[i];
                      newRow["NewColumn"] = string.Join(", ", 
                                            g.Select(row=>row.Field<string>("ProductCode")
                                                     + ", " + row.Field<decimal>("ProductValue")));
                      return newRow;
                    }).CopyToDataTable();
```

**NOTE:** I suppose the ProductCode is string, and the double quotes around `userId` and `NewColumn` values are not part of actual values.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Just one question. Would it be guaranteed that the returned duplicate row will be the first one in the series. If the old table was ordered by the requestId ie. row with requestid 1 being returned?

Comment: @Paul the `RequestId` should be ordered first, in your example, I can see it has been ordered, if your input data can be shuffled, you just need an `OrderBy` before the `GroupBy`.

Comment: Sorry @King one more question why the number 4 in the following line of code and what is actually happening here?                    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) newRow[i] = firstRow[i];

Comment: @Paul that loop goes through the first 4 columns. We use index to make it easy, if using `Column name`, we have to need 4 lines of code to copy all the values in the firstRow to the newRow.

Comment: thank you - can I assume I could use the oldTable.Columns.Count as the index here?